# Is PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor affect somehow on Environment or @PropertySource?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa

Hi i am beginner in Spring and Jpa Integration. While i have tried to configure my database connection,details handler itp. I came across a strange behavior of spring.

First of all, I have 3 config file:

1) RootConfig - contains everything but controllers

2) WebConfig - contains every Bean which is controllers annotated

3) JdbcConfig - contains Beans related with dataSource, this config is imported by RootConfig using this annotation (`@Import(JdbcConfig.class)`).

RootConfig looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@Import(JdbcConfig.class)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "app", excludeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION,value = {EnableWebMvc.class, Controller.class})})
public class RootConfig
{

}
```

JdbcConfig:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:db.properties")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JdbcConfig
{

    @Resource
    public Environment env;


    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource()
    {
        System.out.println(env);
        DriverManagerDataSource ds = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty("dataSource.driverClassName"));
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty("dataSource.Url"));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty("dataSource.username"));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty("dataSource.password"));
        return ds;

    }



    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean(DataSource ds, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter)
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emfb = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emfb.setDataSource(ds);
        emfb.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        emfb.setPackagesToScan("app.model");
        return emfb;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter()
    {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.POSTGRESQL);
        adapter.setShowSql(true);
        adapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        adapter.setDatabasePlatform(env.getProperty("dataSource.dialect"));

        return adapter;
    }



    @Bean
    public BeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor()
    {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }


    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory em) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(em)}}
```

At this moment everything works fine, Environment field is not null value and contains all defined properties. The problem appear when I am trying to add Bean `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` So when I add this Bean to JdbcConfig.class, Environment field became null but when i add this RootConfig Environment again contains all needed values. So is there any known problem with propertySource and this bean? Is `PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` somehow affect on `@PropertySource` or @Autorwired(@Inject/@Ressource) Environment field? Is there any reason why Environment must be configure in main config and it cannot be imported from other config by `@Import`?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related with this spring issue [SPR-8269](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8269).

Can you try setting up PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor bean definition as static?

I also had same problem and I solved in this way.